# monaco-editor use AddAction/AddCommand, how to stopPrapagation?

Tags: stoppropagation, monaco-editor

Here's an action that uses input <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the `run` function.

```js
editor.addAction({
    id: 'runStep',
    label: 'run',
    keybindings: [monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter],
    contextMenuGroupId: 'navigation',
    contextMenuOrder: 1.5,
    run: function(editor){ /*do something*/}
});
```

But how can I `stopPrapagation`?

The parameter of the `run` function is `editor`, not a `keyboardEvent` object.